# Carregar configurações do codeigniter em arquivo externo

Tags: php, codeigniter

Alguem sabe como é que eu faço para carregar todas as configurações do codeigniter em algum arquivo externo, dando um require?

Por exemplo: Um arquivo .css que pega informações do banco de dados!

Alguem sabe como incluir, ou qual arquivo incluir para que ele carregue toda a configuração do banco que já está no application/config/database.php ??

Obrigado desde já...

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara, principalmente o caso com .css. Pelo que entendi, você deseja obter o conteúdo dos arquivos do CI e incluir no banco ou em outro arquivo PHP.

Bem, dê uma olhada no helper `File` do CI e em suas funções para leitura e escrita de arquivos das pastas do site.

O bacana de usar esse helper é que você pode sobrescrever, por exemplo, o arquivo `config.php` ou `database.php`com configurações personalizadas.

Answer (score 0):

```
Carregue as informações com o config->item:
    $this->config->item('nome_da_config');
    
    EX Carregando CSS com URL Completa:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>css/arquivo.css" type="text/css">
```